# WordPress multiple payment gateways selection on WooCommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment

I am novice to WordPress and working on my first website in WordPress. I am using `WordPress 4.9.8` with `WooCommerce 3.5.2`.

The requirement is, I want to provide different payment gateways list to customers on checkout page. e.g. `paypal`, `worldpay`, `stripe` etc., so that they can select the gateway they want and make the payment. I will use payment plugins for it. 
But I am not sure how to provide list of payment gateways in checkout page. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to **WooCommerce > Settings > Payments** to enable/disable the payment gate you want, and if you want to use more payment gate like Stripe, you need to install a plugin like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/

Here is a screenshot showing my Payment Settings screen in WooCommerce, I'm using only PayPal and you can see it's enabled.

[image: WooCommerce Payment Settings]

Answer (score 0):

You can Add all payment method in Woocommerce.
WooCommerce → Settings → Checkout
Take a tour for this article hope it will help you
https://themeisle.com/blog/accept-payments-with-wordpress/
Let me know